# apparmor causes issues on libvirt with custom qemu

Tags: qemu, libvirt, apparmor

I wanted to run libvirt using a customized version of qemu. However, after I installed my version of qemu and rebooted I get the following message in dmesg

> type=1400 audit(1338385059.381:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec"
>   parent=1700 profile="/usr/sbin/libvirtd"
>   name="/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64" pid=1746 comm="libvirtd"
>   requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=0 ouid=0

I tried editing the /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu and added the following line and rebooted

> /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 rmix,

However the issue is still present.
I am really new to apparmor, in fact hadn't read much on it till I found this error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did a workaround, by default when we installed from source, qemu was installed in /usr/local/bin. I configured the path to work in /usr/bin. Now it works fine.. But would still love to know what went wrong initially

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log message indicates that the problem was in the `/usr/sbin/libvirtd` profile; see the `profile="/usr/sbin/libvirtd"` portion of the message. This profile is stored in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd`; this profile *does not* include the `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` abstraction -- this is instead loaded via the profiles in `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/`. See the last lines in the `libvirtd` profile:

```
  # allow changing to our UUID-based named profiles
  change_profile -> @{LIBVIRT}-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*,
```

Probably the easiest answer would be to add the following line to your `local/usr.sbin.libvirtd` file:

```
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 rmix,
```

(Though perhaps it would require `PUx` instead; the main `/usr/sbin/libvirtd` profile currently has `/usr/bin/* PUx,`, which is probably how the `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64` gets executed currently.)

Another approach is to run `aa-logprof`, and allow the tools to prompt you. You may not build the *prettiest* profiles using the tools, but it should be fairly straightforward and have the same security properties as hand-authoring your profiles.

I hope this helps.

Comment: correction: Your post did help though. Adding lines `/usr/local/share/qemu/** r,` and `/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 rmix,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` did work.

Comment: Heh, funny, I missed you on irc by moments and on stack overflow by seven years :)